# Cruisecontrol and cc.net gone?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Just in the process of moving part of our build server and found that all the documentation at thoughtworks.com has gone.

Anyone know if this is permanent or temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's temporary, they have some server troubles.

They are moving to sourceforge.net

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/

Answer (score 1):

The [main site](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) is back up again.  You can also get to it via the sourceforge link Arthur provided.

Answer (score 0):

They've moved it to here: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/overview.html

Comment: Note that this link is for the Java implementation. I believe the OP was asking about the .NET one (implied by his reference to thoughtworks.com.)